# How to submit form in php class

Tags: php, html, oop

I have a PHP file that contains a form and another PHP file defining a class. I want to add the path of the class method in the form's `action` property. How do I do that?

**formfile.php**

```
<form action="classfile.php or it's method" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**classfile.php**

```
<?php

class Db_process extends Db_query { 

public function form_submit() {     
   $user = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];  
  // further process ...
}
```

Comment: actually i'm not sure that you can do it directly, you should declare an instance of your object and then use your method

Comment: *"why minus one ?"* - @mohsin that isn't my downvote, but you may have gotten that because you didn't state what the problem was, and/or any errors you may have gotten. Edit: and your `action="classfile.php or it's method"` looks like you're unsure what to use here.

Comment: wondering why that pending edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17006601 is wanting to overwrite my edit from earlier. Surprised by the accepted one too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *classfile.php* in your form's action attribute to post user's submitted data to *classfile.php* file.

```
<form action="classfile.php" method="post">
```

Now as per your code, `$_POST` array is not available in the scope of your `form_submit()` method. You have to first create an object of `Db_process` class. Then use the instance to call `form_submit()` method and pass the entire `$_POST` array to `form_submit()`. This way it would be easier for you to process user's submitted input data inside the method.

```
class Db_process extends Db_query { 
    public function form_submit($postArray) {     
        $user = isset($postArray['username']) && !empty($postArray['username']) ? $postArray['username'] : null;
        $password = isset($postArray['password']) && !empty($postArray['password']) ? $postArray['password'] : null;

        // further process
    }
}

$Db_process_obj = new Db_process;
$Db_process_obj->form_submit($_POST);
```

Comment: @mohsin You can't directly specify the class's method in the `action` attribute, As I wrote in the answer itself, it should be `classfile.php`.

Comment: ... actually many MVC frameworks _do_ specify the method to be called in the URL. The Controller would have a method called something like `formProcessAction()` which would be called with an URL like `/{{controller}}/formProcess`

Comment: @mohsin I didn't downvote your question, generally I don't downvote questions or answers unless it's a spam or shows absolutely no effort. However, since you have tried *something* on your own and got stuck midway, I'm going to upvote your question. But make sure that you do adequate amount of research on solving the problem on your own before posting a question on SO. Cheers! :-)

Comment: @CD001 OP hasn't mentioned the usage of any MVC architecture in the question. It's a plain PHP stuff, as of now.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul - yeah but you'd said *"You can't directly specify the class's method in the action attribute"* ... which is only strictly true - there are ways to specify which action to call even without bolting an entire framework on. Would result in a much longer and more complicated answer though ;) I just wanted to make the OP aware that it _is_ possible.

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep I will follow as you said, thanks everyone for support